# Load dump from outside the container or inside performance wise

Tags: docker

It's there any noticable difference if I load a mysql dump from the container itself or I use `docker exec -i` to load it from the outside?

Answer (score 0):

The two paths are functionally identical: you're running the same SQL commands against the same database.  As a general rule, I'd suggest avoiding `docker exec` if there's another path to doing what you need, particularly for interacting with a network-accessible service.

Running the `mysql` client requires installing the ordinary tools you need to interact with the database, and once you've done this, you can do it as an unprivileged user.  You could even do it from a different host.  You'll never be confused over whether a file is in host filesystem space or container filesystem space.

`docker exec` requires root-level privileges on the host (if you can `docker exec` then you can also `docker run -v/:/host ...` and change *anything* on the host) and essentially involves getting a root shell on the database server.  Neither of these is really a best practice for ordinary administrative operations.